# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bad magic number for Bundle: 0x0

Tags: java, android, illegalstateexception

I'm trying to fetch data of [this](https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/May/59121517_baking/baking.json) json api

and the first main activity fetched well with name of each recipe but when I click on item to start the detail activity the app just crashed and the eror caused by:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bad magic number for Bundle: 0x0

**main activity**

```
@Override
    public void onClick(BakingItem recipe) {

        ArrayList<BakingItem> selectedRecipe = new ArrayList<>();
        selectedRecipe.add(recipe);

        Context context = this;
        Class destinationClass = DetailsActivity.class;
        Intent intentToStartDetailActivity = new Intent(context, destinationClass);
        Bundle selectedRecipeBundle = new Bundle();
        selectedRecipeBundle.putParcelableArrayList("recipe", selectedRecipe);
        intentToStartDetailActivity.putExtras(selectedRecipeBundle);
        startActivity(intentToStartDetailActivity);

    }
```

**main fragment bundle**:

```
Bundle recipesBundle = new Bundle();
                recipesBundle.putParcelableArrayList(ALL_RECIPES, recipes);
```

**detail activity**:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            Bundle recipeDetails = getIntent().getExtras();

            RecipeDetailsFragment recipeDetailsFragment = new RecipeDetailsFragment();
            recipeDetailsFragment.setArguments(recipeDetails);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.recipe_details, recipeDetailsFragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
```

**detail fragment**:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recipe_details, container, false);

        final TextView RecipeName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recipe_name);
//        final TextView Ingredients = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ingredients);
        String recipeName;

        recipe = new ArrayList<>();

        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            recipe = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("recipe");
        }
        else {
            recipe = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("recipe");
        }

        recipeName=recipe.get(0).getName();
        RecipeName.setText(recipeName);
```

I pass the name of recipe from main to detail and received it well but when I add other details to parcelable class like steps array the app start crashed and this is the parcelable class:

```
public class BakingItem implements Parcelable {

        private int id;
        private String name;
        private ArrayList<StepsItem> steps = null;
        private int servings;

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
            out.writeInt(id);
            out.writeString(name);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putParcelableArrayList("stepsList", steps);
            out.writeBundle(bundle);
            out.writeInt(servings);
        }

        public BakingItem() {
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<BakingItem> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<BakingItem>() {
            @Override
            public BakingItem createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                BakingItem bakingItem = new BakingItem();
                bakingItem.id = in.readInt();
                bakingItem.name                 = in.readString();
                Bundle bundle1 = in.readBundle(StepsItem.class.getClassLoader());
                bakingItem.steps = bundle1.getParcelableArrayList("stepsList");
                bakingItem.servings                 = in.readInt();
                return bakingItem;
            }
            @Override
            public BakingItem[] newArray(int i) {
                return new BakingItem[i];
            }
        };

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public ArrayList<StepsItem> getSteps() {
            return steps;
        }

        public int getServings() {
            return servings;
        }




        public static class StepsItem implements Parcelable {

            private int idSteps;
            private String shortDescription;


            @Override
            public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
                out.writeInt(idSteps);
                out.writeString(shortDescription);
            }

            protected StepsItem(Parcel in) {
                this.idSteps = in.readInt();
                this.shortDescription = in.readString();
            }

            public StepsItem() {
            }

            @Override
            public int describeContents() {
                return 0;
            }

            public static final Creator<StepsItem> CREATOR = new Creator<StepsItem>() {
                @Override
                public StepsItem createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                    return new StepsItem(in);
                }
                @Override
                public StepsItem[] newArray(int i) {
                    return new StepsItem[i];
                }
            };

            public int getId() {
                return idSteps;
            }

            public String getShortDescription() {
                return shortDescription;
            }


        }

    }
```

what the problem with parcelable class ?